# Magento 2: How to remove styles-m.css from category and product page

Tags: php, magento2

How to remove default styles file (styles-l.css, styles-m.css) from category and product page in magento 2.X

Answer (score 5):

```
<page>
   <head>
        <!-- Remove local resources -->
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />

  </head>
..

</page>
```

Add this to catalog_product_view.xml and check